# Reactjs TypeError: Unable to get property 'string' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-select-class for Async options in my react project. i am getting error as "Unable to get property 'string' of undefined or null reference". react-select-class the code is written in react createclass and i converted to es6. Bellow i am giving the modified code . please help me to come out from this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import createClass from 'create-react-class';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select-plus';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';


export default class GithubUsers extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
            backspaceRemoves: true,
            multi: true,
            creatable: false,
        }
    }
    static propTypes ={
        label: PropTypes.string,
    }
    onChange (value) {
        this.setState({
            value: value,
        });
    }

    getUsers (input) {
        if (!input) {
            return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
        }

        return fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${input}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            return { options: json.items };
        });
    }
    gotoUser (value, event) {
        window.open(value.html_url);
    }

    render () {
        const AsyncComponent = this.state.creatable
            ? Select.AsyncCreatable
            : Select.Async;

        return (
            <div className="section">

                <AsyncComponent multi={this.state.multi} value={this.state.value} 
                    onChange={this.onChange} 
                    onValueClick={this.gotoUser} 
                    valueKey="id" labelKey="login" 
                    loadOptions={this.getUsers} 
                    backspaceRemoves={this.state.backspaceRemoves} 
                />


            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default GithubUsers;
```

dependencies

```
    "react-select-plus": "^1.0.0-rc.3.patch12",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
```

error

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'string' of undefined or null reference
./node_modules/react-select-plus/node_modules/react-input-autosize/lib/AutosizeInput.js
C:/Users/manju/Projects/node_modules/react-select-plus/node_modules/react-input-autosize/lib/AutosizeInput.js:28
  25 |   overflow: 'scroll',
  26 |   whiteSpace: 'pre'
  27 | };
> 28 | var AutosizeInput = React.createClass({
  29 |   displayName: 'AutosizeInput',
  30 |   propTypes: {
  31 |     className: React.PropTypes.string,
```

I refereed this Async options with Promises fom https://reactjsexample.com/a-fork-of-react-select-with-support-for-option-groups/ .

Thanks

Comment: The error is about the component named "AutosizeInput" but you posted code is about "GithubUsers". Try upload the correct source code then people would help in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

add after class and remove static block in class

```
GithubUsers.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: what is your react version ?

Comment: "react": "^16.8.6"

Comment: npm install --save prop-types

Answer (score 0):

Just try with `PropTypes.string` rather than `React.PropTypes.string`

hope it helps , feel free for doubts

Comment: AutosizeInput  this component comes inside node modules. not written by me. i changed and tried but still it shows same

Comment: its better not to change node modules directly

Comment: see this once https://github.com/JedWatson/react-input-autosize/issues/84#issuecomment-491507049

Comment: try upgrading react-input-autosize

Comment: github.com/JedWatson/react-input-autosize/issues here they mentioned to install create-react-class i installed .but still same error . react-input-autosize upgraded . iam using latest version only but still same

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem coming from the module "react-select-plus" which is probably consisting AutoSizeInput.js file as a feature.

Try to update "react-select-plus" to the last version with "npm install" and if you still face the same problem, I would prefer not to use it and find another package to use as Select in your app

These are probably similar issues as yours:

[Github](https://github.com/HubSpot/react-select-plus/issues/126)

[Github2](https://github.com/HubSpot/react-select-plus/issues/67)